# URLComponents.url is nil

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl, nsurlcomponents

I'm trying to use `URLComponents` to compose a `URL` as that appears to be what it's for.

However, when I then access the `url` property of the components it is nil.

Example...

```
var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "http://google.com")!
urlComponents.path = "auth/login"
```

Then I do ...

```
print(urlComponents)
```

Output...

```
scheme: http host: google.com path: auth/login
  - scheme : "http"
  - host : "google.com"
  - path : "auth/login"
```

But then...

```
print(urlComponents.url)
```

outputs `nil`.

Am I doing something wrong with this? How do I get the fully formed URL from all this? Thanks

Comment: tried to use NSURLComponents instead of URLComponents ?

Comment: @UmairAfzal I'm using Swift. URLComponents bridges to NSURLComponents (as per docs).

Comment: By any chance you are here cos of raywenderlich? :D

Answer (score 138, accepted):

It looks like `path` parameter's string must start with `/`.

So change `"auth/login"` to `"/auth/login"` will do.

Comment: I was just about to come and answer this myself after a bit more digging in the docs. (Who'd have thought that the docs would explain what's going wrong, haha!) Thanks

Comment: I wonder what is the point in having a dedicated type that constructs an URL for you (as opposed to just building the string manually from scheme, host, etc.) if you still have to look out for these things? sheesh...

Comment: @NicolasMiari it's actually really useful for embedding query parameters and different schemes and hosts into the url etc... Maybe switching between a test and a production host etc...

Comment: Tanks, this really helped me!  Same issue and scratching my head for hours.  Was missing the front "/" from the path.

Answer (score 36):

**TL;DR**

If you're creating a web URL (e.g. `http://example.com/path`), include the `/` because it uses the following template:

```
{scheme}://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}{path}?{query}#{fragment}
```

If you're creating a non web URL (e.g. `mailto:user@example.com`), don't include the `/` because it uses the following template:

```
{scheme}:{path}?{query}%23{fragment}
```

---

To clarify why this is happening, the actual template of [URLComponents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcomponents) is as follows:

```
{scheme}://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}{path}?{query}#{fragment}
```

Notice how there is punctuation (`://`, `:`, `@`, `:`, `?`, `#`) between every two components, *except* for `{port}` and `{path}`.

**Therefore, `{path}` must be prefixed with the punctuation (`/`), otherwise it'll produce an invalid URL.**

In your case you must use :

```
urlComponents.path = "/auth/login"
```

---

Note that even if you omit URLComponents's uncommon fields, you still run into the same problem:

```
{scheme}://{host}{path}?{query}#{fragment}
```

Notice how `{host}` and `{path}` are adjacent in this case as well, with no punctuation separating the two.

You may be wondering why, then, Apple didn't include the punctuation before `{port}`. My guess is because URLComponents can be used to produce any type of URL in the [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) spec, not only Web URLs. E.g. it could easily produce `http://www.example.com/foo`, but it should just as easily produce a URL of the form `mailto:user@example.com`.

URLComponents makes this possible by changing the delimiter between `{scheme}` and `{path}` when `{host}` is omitted:

```
{scheme}:{path}?{query}%23{fragment}
```

Thus when we want to produce a mailto link, we would actually *not* include the `/` in path:

```
urlComponents.scheme = "mailto"
urlComponents.path = "user@example.com"
// urlComponents.url!.absoluteString == "mailto:user@example.com"
```

---

Comparing the properties of URLComponents to URL's properties provides a bit more insight (and reveals a bit of inconsistency):

```
let string = "scheme://user:password@host:123/path/path/path/?query#fragment"
let urlComponents = URLComponents(string: string)!
let url = URL(string: string)!

// these are expected
url.absoluteString == urlComponents.url!.absoluteString
url.scheme == urlComponents.scheme
url.user == urlComponents.user
url.password == urlComponents.password
url.host == urlComponents.host
url.port == urlComponents.port
url.query == urlComponents.query
url.fragment == urlComponents.fragment

// this is unexpected. They should have been equal to each other
url.path != urlComponents.path

url.path == "/path/path/path"
urlComponents.path == "/path/path/path/"

url.pathComponents == ["/", "path", "path", "path"]
url.lastPathComponent == "path"
```

Two things to note:

- `url.path` doesn't have `/` in the suffix.
- `url.pathComponents[0]` is the first `/` in the URL.

---

For an exhaustive list of templates, you can use this code:

```
let componentsCount = Double(8)
let iterations = Int(pow(2, componentsCount))

for i in 0..<iterations {
  var urlComponents = URLComponents()
  var key = ""
  if i & 0b10000000 > 0 { urlComponents.scheme = "scheme"; key += "s" } else { key += " " }
  if i & 0b01000000 > 0 { urlComponents.user = "user"; key += "u" } else { key += " " }
  if i & 0b00100000 > 0 { urlComponents.password = "password"; key += "w" } else { key += " " }
  if i & 0b00010000 > 0 { urlComponents.host = "host"; key += "h" } else { key += " " }
  if i & 0b00001000 > 0 { urlComponents.port = 123; key += "r" } else { key += " " }
  if i & 0b00000100 > 0 { urlComponents.path = "/path"; key += "p" } else { key += " " }
  if i & 0b00000010 > 0 { urlComponents.query = "query"; key += "q" } else { key += " " }
  if i & 0b00000001 > 0 { urlComponents.fragment = "fragment"; key += "f" } else { key += " " }

  if let url = urlComponents.url?.absoluteString {
    print("[\(key)] \(url)")
  } else {
    print("[\(key)] ------- nil --------")
  }
}
```

Which produces the following output:

```
[        ] 
[       f] #fragment
[      q ] ?query
[      qf] ?query#fragment
[     p  ] /path
[     p f] /path#fragment
[     pq ] /path?query
[     pqf] /path?query#fragment
[    r   ] //:123
[    r  f] //:123#fragment
[    r q ] //:123?query
[    r qf] //:123?query#fragment
[    rp  ] //:123/path
[    rp f] //:123/path#fragment
[    rpq ] //:123/path?query
[    rpqf] //:123/path?query#fragment
[   h    ] //host
[   h   f] //host#fragment
[   h  q ] //host?query
[   h  qf] //host?query#fragment
[   h p  ] //host/path
[   h p f] //host/path#fragment
[   h pq ] //host/path?query
[   h pqf] //host/path?query#fragment
[   hr   ] //host:123
[   hr  f] //host:123#fragment
[   hr q ] //host:123?query
[   hr qf] //host:123?query#fragment
[   hrp  ] //host:123/path
[   hrp f] //host:123/path#fragment
[   hrpq ] //host:123/path?query
[   hrpqf] //host:123/path?query#fragment
[  w     ] //:password@
[  w    f] //:password@#fragment
[  w   q ] //:password@?query
[  w   qf] //:password@?query#fragment
[  w  p  ] //:password@/path
[  w  p f] //:password@/path#fragment
[  w  pq ] //:password@/path?query
[  w  pqf] //:password@/path?query#fragment
[  w r   ] //:password@:123
[  w r  f] //:password@:123#fragment
[  w r q ] //:password@:123?query
[  w r qf] //:password@:123?query#fragment
[  w rp  ] //:password@:123/path
[  w rp f] //:password@:123/path#fragment
[  w rpq ] //:password@:123/path?query
[  w rpqf] //:password@:123/path?query#fragment
[  wh    ] //:password@host
[  wh   f] //:password@host#fragment
[  wh  q ] //:password@host?query
[  wh  qf] //:password@host?query#fragment
[  wh p  ] //:password@host/path
[  wh p f] //:password@host/path#fragment
[  wh pq ] //:password@host/path?query
[  wh pqf] //:password@host/path?query#fragment
[  whr   ] //:password@host:123
[  whr  f] //:password@host:123#fragment
[  whr q ] //:password@host:123?query
[  whr qf] //:password@host:123?query#fragment
[  whrp  ] //:password@host:123/path
[  whrp f] //:password@host:123/path#fragment
[  whrpq ] //:password@host:123/path?query
[  whrpqf] //:password@host:123/path?query#fragment
[ u      ] //user@
[ u     f] //user@#fragment
[ u    q ] //user@?query
[ u    qf] //user@?query#fragment
[ u   p  ] //user@/path
[ u   p f] //user@/path#fragment
[ u   pq ] //user@/path?query
[ u   pqf] //user@/path?query#fragment
[ u  r   ] //user@:123
[ u  r  f] //user@:123#fragment
[ u  r q ] //user@:123?query
[ u  r qf] //user@:123?query#fragment
[ u  rp  ] //user@:123/path
[ u  rp f] //user@:123/path#fragment
[ u  rpq ] //user@:123/path?query
[ u  rpqf] //user@:123/path?query#fragment
[ u h    ] //user@host
[ u h   f] //user@host#fragment
[ u h  q ] //user@host?query
[ u h  qf] //user@host?query#fragment
[ u h p  ] //user@host/path
[ u h p f] //user@host/path#fragment
[ u h pq ] //user@host/path?query
[ u h pqf] //user@host/path?query#fragment
[ u hr   ] //user@host:123
[ u hr  f] //user@host:123#fragment
[ u hr q ] //user@host:123?query
[ u hr qf] //user@host:123?query#fragment
[ u hrp  ] //user@host:123/path
[ u hrp f] //user@host:123/path#fragment
[ u hrpq ] //user@host:123/path?query
[ u hrpqf] //user@host:123/path?query#fragment
[ uw     ] //user:password@
[ uw    f] //user:password@#fragment
[ uw   q ] //user:password@?query
[ uw   qf] //user:password@?query#fragment
[ uw  p  ] //user:password@/path
[ uw  p f] //user:password@/path#fragment
[ uw  pq ] //user:password@/path?query
[ uw  pqf] //user:password@/path?query#fragment
[ uw r   ] //user:password@:123
[ uw r  f] //user:password@:123#fragment
[ uw r q ] //user:password@:123?query
[ uw r qf] //user:password@:123?query#fragment
[ uw rp  ] //user:password@:123/path
[ uw rp f] //user:password@:123/path#fragment
[ uw rpq ] //user:password@:123/path?query
[ uw rpqf] //user:password@:123/path?query#fragment
[ uwh    ] //user:password@host
[ uwh   f] //user:password@host#fragment
[ uwh  q ] //user:password@host?query
[ uwh  qf] //user:password@host?query#fragment
[ uwh p  ] //user:password@host/path
[ uwh p f] //user:password@host/path#fragment
[ uwh pq ] //user:password@host/path?query
[ uwh pqf] //user:password@host/path?query#fragment
[ uwhr   ] //user:password@host:123
[ uwhr  f] //user:password@host:123#fragment
[ uwhr q ] //user:password@host:123?query
[ uwhr qf] //user:password@host:123?query#fragment
[ uwhrp  ] //user:password@host:123/path
[ uwhrp f] //user:password@host:123/path#fragment
[ uwhrpq ] //user:password@host:123/path?query
[ uwhrpqf] //user:password@host:123/path?query#fragment
[s       ] scheme:
[s      f] scheme:%23fragment
[s     q ] scheme:?query
[s     qf] scheme:?query%23fragment
[s    p  ] scheme:/path
[s    p f] scheme:/path#fragment
[s    pq ] scheme:/path?query
[s    pqf] scheme:/path?query#fragment
[s   r   ] scheme://:123
[s   r  f] scheme://:123#fragment
[s   r q ] scheme://:123?query
[s   r qf] scheme://:123?query#fragment
[s   rp  ] scheme://:123/path
[s   rp f] scheme://:123/path#fragment
[s   rpq ] scheme://:123/path?query
[s   rpqf] scheme://:123/path?query#fragment
[s  h    ] scheme://host
[s  h   f] scheme://host#fragment
[s  h  q ] scheme://host?query
[s  h  qf] scheme://host?query#fragment
[s  h p  ] scheme://host/path
[s  h p f] scheme://host/path#fragment
[s  h pq ] scheme://host/path?query
[s  h pqf] scheme://host/path?query#fragment
[s  hr   ] scheme://host:123
[s  hr  f] scheme://host:123#fragment
[s  hr q ] scheme://host:123?query
[s  hr qf] scheme://host:123?query#fragment
[s  hrp  ] scheme://host:123/path
[s  hrp f] scheme://host:123/path#fragment
[s  hrpq ] scheme://host:123/path?query
[s  hrpqf] scheme://host:123/path?query#fragment
[s w     ] scheme://:password@
[s w    f] scheme://:password@#fragment
[s w   q ] scheme://:password@?query
[s w   qf] scheme://:password@?query#fragment
[s w  p  ] scheme://:password@/path
[s w  p f] scheme://:password@/path#fragment
[s w  pq ] scheme://:password@/path?query
[s w  pqf] scheme://:password@/path?query#fragment
[s w r   ] scheme://:password@:123
[s w r  f] scheme://:password@:123#fragment
[s w r q ] scheme://:password@:123?query
[s w r qf] scheme://:password@:123?query#fragment
[s w rp  ] scheme://:password@:123/path
[s w rp f] scheme://:password@:123/path#fragment
[s w rpq ] scheme://:password@:123/path?query
[s w rpqf] scheme://:password@:123/path?query#fragment
[s wh    ] scheme://:password@host
[s wh   f] scheme://:password@host#fragment
[s wh  q ] scheme://:password@host?query
[s wh  qf] scheme://:password@host?query#fragment
[s wh p  ] scheme://:password@host/path
[s wh p f] scheme://:password@host/path#fragment
[s wh pq ] scheme://:password@host/path?query
[s wh pqf] scheme://:password@host/path?query#fragment
[s whr   ] scheme://:password@host:123
[s whr  f] scheme://:password@host:123#fragment
[s whr q ] scheme://:password@host:123?query
[s whr qf] scheme://:password@host:123?query#fragment
[s whrp  ] scheme://:password@host:123/path
[s whrp f] scheme://:password@host:123/path#fragment
[s whrpq ] scheme://:password@host:123/path?query
[s whrpqf] scheme://:password@host:123/path?query#fragment
[su      ] scheme://user@
[su     f] scheme://user@#fragment
[su    q ] scheme://user@?query
[su    qf] scheme://user@?query#fragment
[su   p  ] scheme://user@/path
[su   p f] scheme://user@/path#fragment
[su   pq ] scheme://user@/path?query
[su   pqf] scheme://user@/path?query#fragment
[su  r   ] scheme://user@:123
[su  r  f] scheme://user@:123#fragment
[su  r q ] scheme://user@:123?query
[su  r qf] scheme://user@:123?query#fragment
[su  rp  ] scheme://user@:123/path
[su  rp f] scheme://user@:123/path#fragment
[su  rpq ] scheme://user@:123/path?query
[su  rpqf] scheme://user@:123/path?query#fragment
[su h    ] scheme://user@host
[su h   f] scheme://user@host#fragment
[su h  q ] scheme://user@host?query
[su h  qf] scheme://user@host?query#fragment
[su h p  ] scheme://user@host/path
[su h p f] scheme://user@host/path#fragment
[su h pq ] scheme://user@host/path?query
[su h pqf] scheme://user@host/path?query#fragment
[su hr   ] scheme://user@host:123
[su hr  f] scheme://user@host:123#fragment
[su hr q ] scheme://user@host:123?query
[su hr qf] scheme://user@host:123?query#fragment
[su hrp  ] scheme://user@host:123/path
[su hrp f] scheme://user@host:123/path#fragment
[su hrpq ] scheme://user@host:123/path?query
[su hrpqf] scheme://user@host:123/path?query#fragment
[suw     ] scheme://user:password@
[suw    f] scheme://user:password@#fragment
[suw   q ] scheme://user:password@?query
[suw   qf] scheme://user:password@?query#fragment
[suw  p  ] scheme://user:password@/path
[suw  p f] scheme://user:password@/path#fragment
[suw  pq ] scheme://user:password@/path?query
[suw  pqf] scheme://user:password@/path?query#fragment
[suw r   ] scheme://user:password@:123
[suw r  f] scheme://user:password@:123#fragment
[suw r q ] scheme://user:password@:123?query
[suw r qf] scheme://user:password@:123?query#fragment
[suw rp  ] scheme://user:password@:123/path
[suw rp f] scheme://user:password@:123/path#fragment
[suw rpq ] scheme://user:password@:123/path?query
[suw rpqf] scheme://user:password@:123/path?query#fragment
[suwh    ] scheme://user:password@host
[suwh   f] scheme://user:password@host#fragment
[suwh  q ] scheme://user:password@host?query
[suwh  qf] scheme://user:password@host?query#fragment
[suwh p  ] scheme://user:password@host/path
[suwh p f] scheme://user:password@host/path#fragment
[suwh pq ] scheme://user:password@host/path?query
[suwh pqf] scheme://user:password@host/path?query#fragment
[suwhr   ] scheme://user:password@host:123
[suwhr  f] scheme://user:password@host:123#fragment
[suwhr q ] scheme://user:password@host:123?query
[suwhr qf] scheme://user:password@host:123?query#fragment
[suwhrp  ] scheme://user:password@host:123/path
[suwhrp f] scheme://user:password@host:123/path#fragment
[suwhrpq ] scheme://user:password@host:123/path?query
[suwhrpqf] scheme://user:password@host:123/path?query#fragment
```

Notice how none of these are `nil`. If you change `urlComponents.path = "/path"` to `urlComponents.path = "path"`, however, you get a completely different set of templates:

```
[        ] 
[       f] #fragment
[      q ] ?query
[      qf] ?query#fragment
[     p  ] path
[     p f] path#fragment
[     pq ] path?query
[     pqf] path?query#fragment
[    r   ] //:123
[    r  f] //:123#fragment
[    r q ] //:123?query
[    r qf] //:123?query#fragment
[    rp  ] ------- nil --------
[    rp f] ------- nil --------
[    rpq ] ------- nil --------
[    rpqf] ------- nil --------
[   h    ] //host
[   h   f] //host#fragment
[   h  q ] //host?query
[   h  qf] //host?query#fragment
[   h p  ] ------- nil --------
[   h p f] ------- nil --------
[   h pq ] ------- nil --------
[   h pqf] ------- nil --------
[   hr   ] //host:123
[   hr  f] //host:123#fragment
[   hr q ] //host:123?query
[   hr qf] //host:123?query#fragment
[   hrp  ] ------- nil --------
[   hrp f] ------- nil --------
[   hrpq ] ------- nil --------
[   hrpqf] ------- nil --------
[  w     ] //:password@
[  w    f] //:password@#fragment
[  w   q ] //:password@?query
[  w   qf] //:password@?query#fragment
[  w  p  ] ------- nil --------
[  w  p f] ------- nil --------
[  w  pq ] ------- nil --------
[  w  pqf] ------- nil --------
[  w r   ] //:password@:123
[  w r  f] //:password@:123#fragment
[  w r q ] //:password@:123?query
[  w r qf] //:password@:123?query#fragment
[  w rp  ] ------- nil --------
[  w rp f] ------- nil --------
[  w rpq ] ------- nil --------
[  w rpqf] ------- nil --------
[  wh    ] //:password@host
[  wh   f] //:password@host#fragment
[  wh  q ] //:password@host?query
[  wh  qf] //:password@host?query#fragment
[  wh p  ] ------- nil --------
[  wh p f] ------- nil --------
[  wh pq ] ------- nil --------
[  wh pqf] ------- nil --------
[  whr   ] //:password@host:123
[  whr  f] //:password@host:123#fragment
[  whr q ] //:password@host:123?query
[  whr qf] //:password@host:123?query#fragment
[  whrp  ] ------- nil --------
[  whrp f] ------- nil --------
[  whrpq ] ------- nil --------
[  whrpqf] ------- nil --------
[ u      ] //user@
[ u     f] //user@#fragment
[ u    q ] //user@?query
[ u    qf] //user@?query#fragment
[ u   p  ] ------- nil --------
[ u   p f] ------- nil --------
[ u   pq ] ------- nil --------
[ u   pqf] ------- nil --------
[ u  r   ] //user@:123
[ u  r  f] //user@:123#fragment
[ u  r q ] //user@:123?query
[ u  r qf] //user@:123?query#fragment
[ u  rp  ] ------- nil --------
[ u  rp f] ------- nil --------
[ u  rpq ] ------- nil --------
[ u  rpqf] ------- nil --------
[ u h    ] //user@host
[ u h   f] //user@host#fragment
[ u h  q ] //user@host?query
[ u h  qf] //user@host?query#fragment
[ u h p  ] ------- nil --------
[ u h p f] ------- nil --------
[ u h pq ] ------- nil --------
[ u h pqf] ------- nil --------
[ u hr   ] //user@host:123
[ u hr  f] //user@host:123#fragment
[ u hr q ] //user@host:123?query
[ u hr qf] //user@host:123?query#fragment
[ u hrp  ] ------- nil --------
[ u hrp f] ------- nil --------
[ u hrpq ] ------- nil --------
[ u hrpqf] ------- nil --------
[ uw     ] //user:password@
[ uw    f] //user:password@#fragment
[ uw   q ] //user:password@?query
[ uw   qf] //user:password@?query#fragment
[ uw  p  ] ------- nil --------
[ uw  p f] ------- nil --------
[ uw  pq ] ------- nil --------
[ uw  pqf] ------- nil --------
[ uw r   ] //user:password@:123
[ uw r  f] //user:password@:123#fragment
[ uw r q ] //user:password@:123?query
[ uw r qf] //user:password@:123?query#fragment
[ uw rp  ] ------- nil --------
[ uw rp f] ------- nil --------
[ uw rpq ] ------- nil --------
[ uw rpqf] ------- nil --------
[ uwh    ] //user:password@host
[ uwh   f] //user:password@host#fragment
[ uwh  q ] //user:password@host?query
[ uwh  qf] //user:password@host?query#fragment
[ uwh p  ] ------- nil --------
[ uwh p f] ------- nil --------
[ uwh pq ] ------- nil --------
[ uwh pqf] ------- nil --------
[ uwhr   ] //user:password@host:123
[ uwhr  f] //user:password@host:123#fragment
[ uwhr q ] //user:password@host:123?query
[ uwhr qf] //user:password@host:123?query#fragment
[ uwhrp  ] ------- nil --------
[ uwhrp f] ------- nil --------
[ uwhrpq ] ------- nil --------
[ uwhrpqf] ------- nil --------
[s       ] scheme:
[s      f] scheme:%23fragment
[s     q ] scheme:?query
[s     qf] scheme:?query%23fragment
[s    p  ] scheme:path
[s    p f] scheme:path%23fragment
[s    pq ] scheme:path?query
[s    pqf] scheme:path?query%23fragment
[s   r   ] scheme://:123
[s   r  f] scheme://:123#fragment
[s   r q ] scheme://:123?query
[s   r qf] scheme://:123?query#fragment
[s   rp  ] ------- nil --------
[s   rp f] ------- nil --------
[s   rpq ] ------- nil --------
[s   rpqf] ------- nil --------
[s  h    ] scheme://host
[s  h   f] scheme://host#fragment
[s  h  q ] scheme://host?query
[s  h  qf] scheme://host?query#fragment
[s  h p  ] ------- nil --------
[s  h p f] ------- nil --------
[s  h pq ] ------- nil --------
[s  h pqf] ------- nil --------
[s  hr   ] scheme://host:123
[s  hr  f] scheme://host:123#fragment
[s  hr q ] scheme://host:123?query
[s  hr qf] scheme://host:123?query#fragment
[s  hrp  ] ------- nil --------
[s  hrp f] ------- nil --------
[s  hrpq ] ------- nil --------
[s  hrpqf] ------- nil --------
[s w     ] scheme://:password@
[s w    f] scheme://:password@#fragment
[s w   q ] scheme://:password@?query
[s w   qf] scheme://:password@?query#fragment
[s w  p  ] ------- nil --------
[s w  p f] ------- nil --------
[s w  pq ] ------- nil --------
[s w  pqf] ------- nil --------
[s w r   ] scheme://:password@:123
[s w r  f] scheme://:password@:123#fragment
[s w r q ] scheme://:password@:123?query
[s w r qf] scheme://:password@:123?query#fragment
[s w rp  ] ------- nil --------
[s w rp f] ------- nil --------
[s w rpq ] ------- nil --------
[s w rpqf] ------- nil --------
[s wh    ] scheme://:password@host
[s wh   f] scheme://:password@host#fragment
[s wh  q ] scheme://:password@host?query
[s wh  qf] scheme://:password@host?query#fragment
[s wh p  ] ------- nil --------
[s wh p f] ------- nil --------
[s wh pq ] ------- nil --------
[s wh pqf] ------- nil --------
[s whr   ] scheme://:password@host:123
[s whr  f] scheme://:password@host:123#fragment
[s whr q ] scheme://:password@host:123?query
[s whr qf] scheme://:password@host:123?query#fragment
[s whrp  ] ------- nil --------
[s whrp f] ------- nil --------
[s whrpq ] ------- nil --------
[s whrpqf] ------- nil --------
[su      ] scheme://user@
[su     f] scheme://user@#fragment
[su    q ] scheme://user@?query
[su    qf] scheme://user@?query#fragment
[su   p  ] ------- nil --------
[su   p f] ------- nil --------
[su   pq ] ------- nil --------
[su   pqf] ------- nil --------
[su  r   ] scheme://user@:123
[su  r  f] scheme://user@:123#fragment
[su  r q ] scheme://user@:123?query
[su  r qf] scheme://user@:123?query#fragment
[su  rp  ] ------- nil --------
[su  rp f] ------- nil --------
[su  rpq ] ------- nil --------
[su  rpqf] ------- nil --------
[su h    ] scheme://user@host
[su h   f] scheme://user@host#fragment
[su h  q ] scheme://user@host?query
[su h  qf] scheme://user@host?query#fragment
[su h p  ] ------- nil --------
[su h p f] ------- nil --------
[su h pq ] ------- nil --------
[su h pqf] ------- nil --------
[su hr   ] scheme://user@host:123
[su hr  f] scheme://user@host:123#fragment
[su hr q ] scheme://user@host:123?query
[su hr qf] scheme://user@host:123?query#fragment
[su hrp  ] ------- nil --------
[su hrp f] ------- nil --------
[su hrpq ] ------- nil --------
[su hrpqf] ------- nil --------
[suw     ] scheme://user:password@
[suw    f] scheme://user:password@#fragment
[suw   q ] scheme://user:password@?query
[suw   qf] scheme://user:password@?query#fragment
[suw  p  ] ------- nil --------
[suw  p f] ------- nil --------
[suw  pq ] ------- nil --------
[suw  pqf] ------- nil --------
[suw r   ] scheme://user:password@:123
[suw r  f] scheme://user:password@:123#fragment
[suw r q ] scheme://user:password@:123?query
[suw r qf] scheme://user:password@:123?query#fragment
[suw rp  ] ------- nil --------
[suw rp f] ------- nil --------
[suw rpq ] ------- nil --------
[suw rpqf] ------- nil --------
[suwh    ] scheme://user:password@host
[suwh   f] scheme://user:password@host#fragment
[suwh  q ] scheme://user:password@host?query
[suwh  qf] scheme://user:password@host?query#fragment
[suwh p  ] ------- nil --------
[suwh p f] ------- nil --------
[suwh pq ] ------- nil --------
[suwh pqf] ------- nil --------
[suwhr   ] scheme://user:password@host:123
[suwhr  f] scheme://user:password@host:123#fragment
[suwhr q ] scheme://user:password@host:123?query
[suwhr qf] scheme://user:password@host:123?query#fragment
[suwhrp  ] ------- nil --------
[suwhrp f] ------- nil --------
[suwhrpq ] ------- nil --------
[suwhrpqf] ------- nil --------
```